# How can I distribute iOS apps that have been rejected from the App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

I have made multiple simple but fun apps for iPhone in the past few months and have had them rejected by Apple during the approval process.

I have put many weeks or months of effort in some cases. I just hate to have these apps go to waste without anyone downloading them.

Since those apps of mine are never going to see the light of the day on the App Store, is there a way I can let family and friends download those apps if I host those binaries on my website? Can anyone tell me the process or walk through instructions?

Are they simple enough that if I post them on Facebook most average users are going to get it? Is there already a website out there that lets users like me (with unapproved apps) to host those files for everyone in the world to download them?

Comment: Are they permanently rejected? Or can you just fix a few things?

Comment: Some of them are permanently rejected and others are rejected on the grounds that they are too simple! Imagine that, a game that is too simple for them to host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look to [testflight](https://testflightapp.com).

You just need an email that can be accessed on the iPhone and add the specific user to test flight, once he is register you can get the iPhone id and add it to the provisioning profile.

When you create the build and upload it , the users are notified by email and the app is installed remotely by a few clicks.

Answer (score 3):

You can authorize a limited number of users to test your app through ad hoc provisioning.  The free service provided by http://www.testflightapp.com makes the over-the-air distribution and provisioning process fairly simple.

Comment: So I have to specifically give access to users i know and gather their device IDs to create provisioning profiles. I thought there is a limit of 100 provisioning profiles allowed per account per year? Man, I wish there was a easier way but I guess the only other option is to tell everyone to jailbreak their phones. That's not gonna happen.

Comment: You got it.  The walls are pretty high around Apple's garden.

Answer (score 1):

You might find these links useful
http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution/

https://testflightapp.com/

Good luck
Harv

Answer (score 0):

Why not just open-source them? You’re probably not going to make a lot of money distributing them with TestFlight or even Cydia. Instead, clean the code up to remove any proprietary things you don’t want to include (API keys, etc.) and put it on GitHub. Not only will this help the community, but you can use your GitHub account as a kind of résumé for future employers or clients. What’s more, you might even get free help with your code if someone forks your game and makes changes!

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but could Enterprise developer's license help here, as long as you are not selling them apps?

Just a thought.